# selectize: get text and value from multiple selectize elements

Tags: jquery, html, selectize.js

I am using multiple seletize elements (select). The user can select from multiple options and just before submit I want to show their selected text (and its value) in a modal.

With selectize, I seem to be able to get the value (by val()) but I am not able to get the text (label).

So for example, the option City has:

```html
<select name="city">
  <option value="1"> Melbourne </option>
  <option value="2"> Sydney </option>
  <option value="3"> Mumbai </option>
</select>
```

My create code is working fine, I just want to get the value and the text, so if the user selects Melbourne i want to be able to get value = 1 and text = Melbourne.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`?

Comment: text : *$(":selected",this).text()* ,value : this.value

Comment: Hi, @Bala  I had already tried  .text () ;  but it always shows empty in alert popup . Anyways thanks for the response  .

Comment: Could you make sample in  fiddle  , we will try to give solution ..

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/n0urwz9e/ its working perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not creating a multiple selectbox.

Create a multiple selectbox like this.

```
<select name="city" multiple="multiple" id="city">
    <option value="1"> Melbourne </option>
    <option value="2"> Sydney </option>
    <option value="3"> Mumbai </option>
    </select> 
<button type="button" id="get_values">Show values</button>
```

JS to retrieve the value and text goes like this

```
document.getElementById('get_values').onclick = function() {
   var x=document.getElementById('city');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
        if(x.options[i].selected ==true)
        {
            alert(x.options[i].text);
            alert(x.options[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Check this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n0urwz9e/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. created function for select element to get text.

```js
function textChanged(){
   alert($("#city").val());
  alert($("#city option:selected").text());
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city" name="city" onChange="textChanged();">
    <option value="1"> Melbourne </option>
    <option value="2"> Sydney </option>
    <option value="3"> Mumbai </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It works perfectly for .val() but shows nothing with .text() in alert popup. Tried InnerHTML , but that too didn't help me .

Comment: please check snippet. I am getting text alert.

Comment: i'm too not getting for text